# Using UHF RF READER (VM-5GA) with raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, python-2.x

I am having trouble with configuring the serial communication of raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie OS.

I want to connect my UHF RFID READER to my raspberry pi 3.

This UHF RFID reader has already built in DB9 having the pins 5V,GND,RX and TX.

My wiring is

```
TX to RX
RX to TX
GND to GND
5V to 5V
```

My code is

```py
import serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.2)

while True:
     rcv = port.readline()
     if len(rcv) > 10:
     print "Tag Detected: " + rcv
```

Comment: The Pi's RX/TX are 3V3.  It is not safe to connect RX to a 5V device.  You can damage or destroy the Pi.

Comment: @joan 

I barely need help because I am new to this Raspberry Pi and also the UHF RFID Reader we are using is not commonly used. We bought this UHF RFID reader (VM-5GA) from china. They don't give enough instructions on how can we interface it with raspberry Pi. Unlike other RFID reader, they have just something to be installed in the raspberry Pi then boom It works !